sum of binomial coefficient (summation formula)
i have to find the summation formula of this sum : $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\binom{n}k$
by using the following hint:
Develop the rational function (i.e., the quotient of two polynomials)
$$
\frac{(x+1)^{n+1}-1}{(n+1)x}
$$
into a sum.
Unfortunately after many tries I still have no idea how to solve the hint, let alone how to apply the result to the actual exercise.
Thank you in advance :)

Can you write $(x+1)^{n+1}$ as a sum involving binomial coefficients? What happens when you subtract $1$ from that sum and divide by $x$?

Another approach to the original problem: consider the polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom nk x^k$ and integrate it.

thats what i did but then i got stuck at $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+1}k x^{k-1} - \frac{1}{x}$

That's helpful context to edit into the original post. You should have $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}$ instead of $\sum_{k=0}^n$. Can you see that your expression is the same as $\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n+1}{j+1} x^j$? Could you finish from there?

yes, i think i got it! thank you so much :)
